# Manipulating the input of the form Django

Tags: python, django, input, django-forms, django-views

I have a form working. I want to change the input of a form. When user write down (s: something) I want to change this as a link in for loop that I list these inputs. So after the changing (s: something) will change to as it is. It will be same but it will have a link to example.com/something. It's like referencing stuff but not just link. I want to create and use a kind of tag or something. How can I do this? Any opinions would help. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you're wish to change (s: something) to `<a href="http://example.com/something"> something</a>`. Like it happens in Twitter with usernames and hashtags? Check this out: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1445/ You will need to modify the code snippet to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes I exactly want it. Is this changes all '@something's to link in the page?

Comment: Yes, that is what it does.